# How do I make a randomizer within an autoresponse?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I'd like to make it so that when you say a certain thing, you get one out of many possible responses.
The code I have right now is:

```
      client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '<response trigger>') {
    msg.channel.send('<response>');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the if statement, put in

```
var responseList = [
"Response one",
"Response two",
"Response three",
"And so on"

const response = Math.floor(Math.random() * responseList.length)

message.channel.send(responseList[response]
```

You can add as many responses as you like and it'll still work.